# I can not get image cropping to work: Jcrop, paperclip, and rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, jcrop

I went through the railscast walk-through http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?autoplay=true . I am able to upload an image using Paperclip and select my crop area. The problem is that when I click submit the image is not cropped. I don't think the image is being reprocessed. I am using all the code from the rails cast. I just changed the variable names to fit my project(@product instead of @user, image instead of avatar etc... )

Here is my products model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'title'
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true
    validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
    validates :title, :uniqueness => true
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x100#", :large => "500x500>" }, :processors => [:cropper]
    attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
    after_update :reprocess_image, :if => :cropping?

    def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  def image_geometry(style = :original)
    @geometry ||= {}
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.path(style))
  end

  private

  def reprocess_image
    image.reprocess!
  end



end
```

Here is my crop.html.erb file. The controller redirects to this page after I submit a new product form with an attached image.

```
<% content_for(:head) do%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min", "jcrop/jquery.Jcrop" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#crop_box').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 3/2,
            onSelect: update_crop,
            onChange: update_crop,
            setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
        }); 
    });


function update_crop(coords) {
  var rx = 100/coords.w;
  var ry = 100/coords.h;
  $('#preview').css({
    width: Math.round(rx * <%= @product.image_geometry(:large).width %>) + 'px',
    height: Math.round(ry * <%= @product.image_geometry(:large).height %>) + 'px',
    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
  });
  var ratio = <%= @product.image_geometry(:original).width %> / <%= @product.image_geometry(:large).width %>;
  $("#crop_x").val(Math.round(coords.x * ratio));
  $("#crop_y").val(Math.round(coords.y * ratio));
  $("#crop_w").val(Math.round(coords.w * ratio));
  $("#crop_h").val(Math.round(coords.h * ratio));
}
</script>

<% end %>

<%= image_tag @product.image.url(:large), :id => "crop_box" %>

<h4>Preview:</h4>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
  <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:large), :id => "preview" %>
</div>

<% form_for @product do |f| %>
  <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h] %>
    <%= f.text_field attribute, :id => attribute %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Crop" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This next piece of code is the paperclip processor from the railscast video. It is supposed to be the code that processes the actual cropping based on the crop selection.

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        crop_command + super.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        " -crop '#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}'"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure what is going wrong. I am sure I am missing something though. I would really appreciate if someone who is more familiar with image cropping than myself could help me out here.

Comment: any luck? Spencer? Would definitely appreciate your thoughts...As I am typing this -- I wonder if the @attachment is "called" the right thing in module Paperclip.

Comment: I actually got it to work by changing the cropper.rb processor to this. https://github.com/SpencerCooley/depot/blob/master/lib/paperclip_processors/cropper.rb . The railscast was a little bit outdated so the newer version of paperclip parsed the (crop_w,crop_h,crop_x,crop_y) differently. It works perfectly now.

Comment: add an answer if you got it to work....